# What is $ \sum_{n \,\text{prime}}\cos(2 \pi x \ln(n)) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I want to re-evaluate the infinite sum used in this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265112276_FAVORED_CARDINALITIES_OF_SCALES) over just the primes.

They have (presumably the author just looked this up in a table or book, because it's not really derived, and setting $\sigma$ = 0):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty Cos(2\ \pi\ x\ Log\ n ) = Re\ \zeta(2\ \pi\ i\ x) $$

At any rate, does anyone know what this infinite sum evaluates to if n is restricted over just the primes?:

$$ \sum_{n\ \epsilon\ Primes}^\infty Cos(2\ \pi\ x\ Log\ n ) = \ ?$$

Comment: I see no reason to think there is a closed form for this.  In fact (for real $x$) the term does not go to zero, so you will need to tell us what extended sense of convergence you have in mind.  Maybe "setting $\sigma=0$" is illegal even in the cited paper?  They even say their series converges only for $\sigma > 1$.

Comment: Probably you can write a "closed form" in terms of the prime zeta function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html

Comment: it doesn't converge @MarcoCantarini

Answer (score 1):

As a start,
note that
$\cos(z)
=\Re e^{iz}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty Cos(2\ \pi\ x\ Log\ n ) 
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Re e^{2\ \pi\ i\ x\ Log\ n }\\ 
&=\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{2\ \pi\ i\ x\ Log\ n }\\ 
&=\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2\ \pi\ i\ x }\\ 
&= \Re\ \zeta(2\ \pi\ i\ x)\\
\end{array}
$

If you do the same thing for primes,
you get

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{P}} Cos(2\ \pi\ x\ Log\ n ) 
&=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{P}} \Re e^{2\ \pi\ i\ x\ Log\ n }\\ 
&=\Re\sum_{n\in \mathbb{P}} e^{2\ \pi\ i\ x\ Log\ n }\\ 
&=\Re\sum_{n\in \mathbb{P}} n^{2\ \pi\ i\ x }\\ 
\end{array}
$

I'm not sure where to go from here.